# d3 Click Events Not Firing

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

I'm creating an app that takes in topoJSON and draws a state divided by all its zip codes. The map draws correctly on the page and now I'm trying to add functionality where if a user clicks a zip code a click event fires that grabs the ID of the element they just clicked. I'm trying to learn angular as part of this project, but that does nothing to help you since the map doesn't 'exist' on the actual front-end HTML page but is instead drawn by D3.

I've tried attaching a click listener to the paths by using the '.on' d3 functionality, but that doesn't appear to work. The full function to draw the map is included below:

```
makeMap () {
    var self = this
    this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/storiesofsolidarity/us-data/gh-pages/geography/zcta/Illinois.topo.json').subscribe(response => {
          var width = 960
        var height = 700;

        var svg = this.d3.select( "body" )
          .append( "svg" )
          .attr( "width", width )
          .attr( "height", height );

        var g = svg.append( "g" )
          .attr('class', 'state')
          .on('click', function() {
            console.log('g firing')
        });

        var albersProjection = this.d3.geoAlbers()
          .scale( 6000 )
          .rotate( [90,0] )
          .center( [4, 40] )
          .translate( [width/2,height/2] );

         console.log(response.json())

        var geoPath = this.d3.geoPath()
          .projection( albersProjection );

        var zips = g.selectAll( "path" )
            .data(topojson.feature(response.json(), response.json().objects["Illinois.geo"]).features)
            .enter()
            .append( "path" )
            .attr( "fill", "#FF0000" )
            .attr( "d", geoPath )
            .attr( "class", "zip-borders")
            .attr( 'id', function(d, i){
              return response.json().objects['Illinois.geo'].geometries[i].id
            })
            .on('click', function (){
                console.log('firing on path')
            });
            console.log('done')
        })
   }
```

I can set up a d3 event that fires on clicking the SVG - but can't get one to fire on a click on the 'g' element or the 'path' elements contained within that g element. I've looked at a lot of examples and don't see why this shouldn't be working - possibly due to some weird integration issue with angular?

I've been banging my head against this for a while and any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The issue was in our CSS file - we had a CSS style setting on 'pointer-events' that we had to remove.

Comment: Share the CSS that defines the fill of `zip-borders`.

Comment: This was the problem. We had a css-property specifying 'pointer events' that was causing our issues. We removed it and things began to function normally. Thanks for your help!