# Image onLoad event is not triggered using Chrome on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, d3.js

I am using [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) and [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) ([scala-js-d3](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3)) to draw an SVG in a web application. The problem I have is that for my background image the `load` event is not triggered when using Chrome on iOS (iPhone). It does trigger when using Chrome on Windows. The image itself is visible on all platforms.

Here is how I add the image:

```
d3.select("#backgroundImg")
  .append("image")
  .attr("id", "graphBackgroundImage")
  .attr("width", "1954px")
  .attr("height", "1532px")
  .attr("xlink:href", "img/maps/map.png")
  // TODO this load event does not trigger on iOS!
  .on("load", (_: EventTarget) => { println("image loaded") } : Unit)
  .on("error", (_: EventTarget) => { prinltn("an error has occured") } : Unit)
```

On Windows this creates the following svg dom element (and everything works as expected):

```
<g id="backgroundImg">
  <image id="graphBackgroundImage" width="1954px" height="1532px" xlink:href="img/maps/map.png"></image>
</g>
```

It is a bit hard to debug on the iPhone I have, so this is all I found out so far. I just know that `image loaded` is not logged when using Chrome on iOS (there is also no `an error has occured` log).

Comment: Is there a playground where i can test some solutions?

Comment: If you want to pay a bit, there's Browserstack, it has a great variation of phone devices to choose from :)
https://www.browserstack.com/

There might also be some Free alternatives, try have a look here:
https://alternativeto.net/software/browserstack/?license=free

Comment: did you try using on("onload") ?. The reason why I am asking to try this is chrome in iOS is pretty much based on webkit and not blink.  So there will be differences in Chrome on iOS and windows

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar topic (minus the scala JS) about this, here is the link:  [Topic One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091685/svg-with-mask-not-seen-on-chrome)

Here is another one that may help:
[Topic Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335330/d3-click-events-not-firing)

The solution ended up being that they had "css-properties specifying 'pointer events'"

Can you send your url for review.  I think I may have another idea if neither of the two links help, but I need to see more of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunatley neither of the two links show a similar scenario since I am neither having a problem with pointer-events (where a css setting was the culprit) nor does my page not render correctly.  Also, the code base I am working on is not open-sourced and not hosted on a public website, so it's hard to provide a url.

Comment: Understood, I apologize I can't help more.  I will look around a little and see if there is anything else I can find that might help.  Best of luck, one of these code masters will help I'm sure.

Comment: @FlorianBaierl I understand it's not OK to share the private link out. But you still have the choice to build a simple demo that reproduces this issue then others who want to help could dive into and figure out the root cause. Why not give it a try?